# Dynamic updating with database info in Django with Ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, database, django

I'm currently trying to dynamically update a portion of a user-authenticated website to display (on click) several entries found in a database (specifically referring to books in a user's library). I would also like to give the user functionality to add and remove items associated with them on the same page that will dynamically update.

If the user clicks on "my library" I would like the main body of the page to populate with the books found in the user's library. I would also like the user to have the ability to add books to their library without going to a separate page.

Does anyone have any idea how I could do something like this in Django (with Ajax)? All the tutorials I have managed to find that do something similar are using PHP or ASP. Anyone that could point me to a tutorial or give me general advice on how I could learn how to do this with the Django framework specifically is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you've seen tutorials in PHP/ASP, why should it be any different in Django? The exact same principles apply: you need some Javascript that posts to server-side views to index/add books.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a model, you will need to pass the data object to your view. From the view you then render your template with the data. For example:

In your view, pass the books objects to the view's context like this :

```
books = Books.objects.all()
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html',{'books': books})
```

and then in your template (mytemplate.html) do like this:

```
<label for="book"> District</label>
<select  id="book" name="book">
  {% for book in books %}
  <option id="{{ book.name }}" value="{{ book.number }}">{{ book.name }} </option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```